# How to change row color base on the values in column 1?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to know how to change row color of a number of rows base on the value in column 1. Lets say in A1 to A5 I have the value "100" and A6 to A10 I have the value "150", i want to be able to change the color of rows 1 to 5 to blue because A1 to A5 has the value "100" and so forth with A6 to A10 to another color because of value "150". Pretty much I need to change the color to the same if the value are the same. My code works but it just changes to all blue and not different color each time the value changes.

EDIT ANSWER:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim holder As String
Set UsedRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

FirstRow = UsedRng(1).Row
LastRow = UsedRng(UsedRng.Cells.Count).Row
r = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)
g = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)
b = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)
holder = Cells(FirstRow, 1).Value
For i = FirstRow To LastRow    '<--| loop through rows index
    myColor = RGB(r, g, b)
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = holder Then
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Interior.Color = myColor
    Else
        holder = Cells(i, 1).Value
        r = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)
        g = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)
        b = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(r, g, b)
 End If
Next i
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you do not use conditional formatting for this?

Comment: @M.Doerner because the value is unknown, I'm just using "100" and "150" as examples.

Comment: Note that the code in your edit does not fully do what you described. It gives a new colour to each cluster of consecutive rows with the same value in column 1. However, it will not produce the same colour for non-consecutive rows with the same value in the first column.

Comment: @M.Doerner you are correct, but 99.9% of the time the same value will fall consecutive rows and not all over the place because that column will be sorted then color coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to do a random color when value changes loop:

```
Sub Color()

lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For i = 2 To lastrow

        If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then

            r = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)
            g = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)
            b = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 255)

            Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(r, g, b)

        Else

            Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(r, g, b)

        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

The result will look like this:

[image]

Comment: close but i'll choose it as a answer even though on my edit post is the final result.

Comment: Glad to hear that my answer lead you to right solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can begin with this code

```
Sub main()
    Dim myCol As Long, i As Long

    For i = 1 To 10 '<--| loop through rows index
        With Cells(i, 1) '<--| reference cell at row i and column 1
            Select Case .value
                Case 100
                    myCol = vbBlue
                Case 150
                    myCol = vbRed
                Case Else
                    myCol = vbWhite
            End Select
            .EntireRow.Interior.Color = myCol
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you asking me that? You tell me! You may enhance your post with some examples...

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can check Cells A1 to A10 for value of 100 and if all cells contains 100, paint all rows from 1 to 10 with Blue color.

```
Sub ColorMeBlue()

    Dim iStart, iEnd As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim b As Boolean
    iStart = 1: iEnd = 10

    b = False

    '~~> We will set b to true if all cells in A1:A10 conatins 100
    For i = iStart To iEnd
        If Cells(i, 1) = 100 Then
            b = True
        End If
    Next

    '~~> We will paint Blue if b is true
    If b Then
        Rows("1:10").Interior.Color = vbBlue
    End If

End Sub
```

You can use same logic to for your next set rows.

The reason I didn't put the entire code is so that you can practice on your own.

Comment: Check my updated post, i got it to work but it's not changing color each time a new value is found. Not sure how to code it to stay the same if the value is the same and change if the value changes.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. I answered as I understood. Give more details/test data.

Comment: I do not know the values in column 1, so i cannot preidentify that it will equal "100" or "150". I will only check the values, and if they are the same, make it the same color.

Comment: `I will only check the values...`, on what basis you'll check? Value = ?/ value > ?/ value < ?. Also do you want to check value in 5 rows set or individual row?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your reply to my comment, I assume you neither know the exact values in the first column nor how many different values there are.

To make my answer not too complicated, I assume further that the first column only contains non-negative numbers. If this is not the case, you just have to map the datatype in the column to that number range.

Under the ssumption above you can use the following code.

```
Public Sub SetRowColorBasedOnValue()
    Dim firstColumn As Range
    Set firstColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(1)

    Dim minValue As Double
    Dim maxValue As Double

    minValue = Application.Min(firstColumn)
    maxValue = Application.Max(firstColumn)

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim shade As Double
    For Each cell In firstColumn.Cells
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            shade = (CDbl(cell.Value2) - minValue) / (maxValue - minValue)
            SetRowColorToShade cell, shade
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub SetRowColorToShade(ByVal cell As Range, ByVal shade As Double)
    With cell.EntireRow.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
        .TintAndShade = shade
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Admittedly, the colours can be very similar. If you are using Excel 2013 or later you can use `cell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = HSL(hue,saturation,chroma)` instead of setting tint and shade to change the hue based on the value. This provides much more different colours.

Comment: that is correct, i neither know the value or how many value there are but what i didn't specify was that the value should be a string and not a integer because that value could be have characters in there as well.

Comment: If you also have strings in there, you will have to hash them to a number if you want to use the approach described above. To find out how to do that, just search on SO.